# I can't run postgresql server after I change ssl = on in postgresql.conf in Windows Server 2012.

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

After changing ssl = on in postgresql.conf, postgresql server can't run anymore. What settings are needed more to enable SSL. I am using postgresql on **Windows Server 2012**.

Comment: Start by checking you have all _certificates_ in place. See [PostgreSQL documentation about SSL certs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html#SSL-FILE-USAGE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my research
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html#SSL-FILE-USAGE

As in the link, you need to create a Self-signed Certificate first.

To do that you need OPENSSL. I use apache 2.4.12 and it has OpenSSL 1.01.1m ver.

You can also download and install easily from internet.

Then go to the folder that Openssl install from cmd. In my case, "cd C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache 24\bin".

Then execute the command as in the above link says.

openssl req -new -text -out server.req

openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out server.key

openssl req -x509 -in server.req -text -key server.key -out server.crt (In Windows OS you can only do those steps.)

Then copy server.key C:\ (Anywhere you want..)

copy server.crt C:\

Look for the files you copy (server.key & server.crt) and copy them to PostgreSQL data folder.

Then change ssl = on in postgresql.conf file.

Restart the postgresql service.

Done!!!

Comment: Note that one might need to use Cygwin for the commands tu run fine.